# Op-amps other than 741 not simulating in Proteus

Tags: operational-amplifier

Trying to simulate a voltage comparator in Proteus using [LM339](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm339-d.pdf), 392 or 293 I cannot get anywhere but the 741 works fine. Am I missing something? The same  op-amps seem to be fine in Tikercad.

Comment: Do you know that some comparator need a ... resistor on output ?

Comment: Comparitors and op-amps are similar but different! Many comparators have open-collector or open-drain outputs to allow them to be paralleled in OR configuration.

Comment: Also, please stop using 741s, they are older than your grandma. There is no reason, ever, to use them in new designs and hasn't been since about 1975. Literally any other op amp is better than a 741.

Comment: @IanBland To me, it doesn’t sound like the OP is trying to use a 741, he is trying to use several others, but can only get a 741 to do what he expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*...Proteus using ML339, 392 or 293 I cannot...* I think you mean LM339,392 and 293.

*Am I missing something?* It's because you need a pull-up resistor.

[image]

As you can see in the datasheet, it explains. Next time try to check the datasheet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: To explain: these comparators have an open collector output. That means that the output is either connected to Ground (or -ve) or is in a high impedance state, effectively "not connected to Ground". So the resistor will in that state pull it up to +ve (or whatever the resistor is connected to).

Comment: Thanks for support @IanBland

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is the pull up resistor I was missing. Will try to include them later in the day.

Comment: How do I respond to a reply that helps me? I want to say thanks thumbs up but the site does not seem to have that, or am I missing something?

Comment: On top of the answer, the little up arrow means that's a helpfull answer, down arrow that's not.